# Alwayson fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica takes a long time to return results

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

Our 2 nodes full sync mode Alwayson cluster has 20 databases which allocated into 4 different AG groups (9, 6, 3, 2). We set backup preference as on 'preferred secondary'. Find out that fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica function takes 10 - 14 seconds to return results for pre-check each database which causing backup to take a long time with HADR_CLUSAPI_CALL wait.  It seems no matter which one of four backup preference methods for Alwayson, you needs to relied on fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica to return its backup preference. How to fix this problem since the fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica is a system function which hard to modify?

we use SQL 2016 Enterprise, SP2 on latest CU. on VM

Comment: There was a fix in [SQL Server 2019 CU9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5000642-cumulative-update-9-for-sql-server-2019-97ad5c3e-e002-4b6d-b566-698bf70ca44a#bkmk_13651126) that addresses this, but I'm not aware of a similar but affecting SQL Server 2016 SP2. Is there any chance your Windows cluster is running with mixed Windows OS versions? (Ex, some servers running Windows 2012, others 2016)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We use WIN server 2016 standard + SQL 2016 SP2. Both Primary and secondary are identical setup.